# How to make a bar/column represent a value for a whole hour

Tags: apexcharts

I have a data series where each value is valid for a whole hour. Each x-value timestamp represents the start of that hour. For the life of me I can't find how to make a bar/column that would be as wide as the whole hour on the x-axis (at best still leaving some margin to the next, though...). All values just appear as a thin line exactly on top of each hour. While I can set some stroke width, it will only work for certain chart widths acceptably, but what I would need is to just make the column automatically "1h" wide (or "59min" for a small gap to the next). Is there any trick to achieve that?